# building json in java script dynamically not working

Tags: javascript, json

i try to build json structure object dynamically according examples i saw in the net but with no success.
this is the json i try to build:

```
{
    "campaigns": [
        {
             "campaign_id":,
             "profile_id":,
             "state":,
             "goal": 

        },
        {
             "campaign_id":,
             "profile_id":,
             "state":,
             "goal":
        }       
    ]
}
```

and this is the code :
this function called each time there is data to build the campaigns (in the json) element

```
var campaignsJson ={};
campaignsJson.campaigns =[];


var i = 0;
  function buildJson(stateCampaignId,
                     profile_id,
                     stateSelectedValue,
                     dailyImpressionGoalValue,
                     pacingValue,
                     segmentGroupTargetsUpdatedataValue,
                     frequencytypeProfileValue,
                     frequencysetProfileValue
                     )
  {

    campaignsJson.campaigns[i].campaign_id = stateCampaignId;
    campaignsJson.campaigns[i].profile_id = profile_id;
    campaignsJson.campaigns[i].state = stateSelectedValue;
    campaignsJson.campaigns[i].goal = dailyImpressionGoalValue;  
    i++;
    var campaignsJsonstringify = JSON.stringify(campaignsJson);
    alert(campaignsJsonstringify);
  }
```

it gives me "cannot set property campaign_id of undefined" 
what does it means ?and why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just before

```
campaignsJson.campaigns[i].campaign_id = stateCampaignId;
```

add this :

```
campaignsJson.campaigns[i] = {};
```

So that there is an object onto which you'll be able to set properties.

Now, please, don't speak of "JSON structure". What you build is a plain standard JavaScript object while [JSON](http://json.org/) is only the string based exchange format.

Comment: +1 for insisting on proper use of the term JSON. Building JSON dynamically would involve String concatenations (and is a silly thing to do in Javascript).